# Ruby HMAC signing issue

Tags: ruby, sign, hmac

I got an issue with HMAC. 
I have to sign a form before sending it to a bank. 
They only provide an example in PHP in their documentation.

I have a hex key to sign my data (e.g. `FCEBA61A884A938E7E7FE4F5C68AA7F4A349768EE5957DDFBE99C1D05A09CBACF1FCF0A7084CB2E4CBA95193176C4395DE7F39EA9DBEBEF0907D77192AAE3E8A`).

In the PHP exemple, they do this with the key before signing the data:

```
 $key = "FCEBA61A884A938E7E7FE4F5C68AA7F4A349768EE5957DDFBE99C1D05A09CBACF1FCF0A7084CB2E4CBA95193176C4395DE7F39EA9DBEBEF0907D77192AAE3E8A";
 $message = "param1=a&param2=b";

 $binKey = pack('H*', $key);
 $signature = hash_hmac('sha512', $msg, $binKey);
 echo $signature;

 // => a3efb70368bee502ea57a1a4708cac8912a5172075ea8dec2de2770dfbb4c8fb587f03fdadc0ca4f9e1bb024cfda12866295b259f5fb4df2fe14d960874a68ab
```

I don't understand why they pack the key and if I should do something similar with my key.
I did the following in my Ruby code:

```
key = "FCEBA61A884A938E7E7FE4F5C68AA7F4A349768EE5957DDFBE99C1D05A09CBACF1FCF0A7084CB2E4CBA95193176C4395DE7F39EA9DBEBEF0907D77192AAE3E8A"
message = "param1=a&param2=b"

digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha512')
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, key, message)

puts signature

# => d817611845246640d1224a0874bf60fed0956a367aa3069b7947cbec56903bb5d8c54df170f5504c586dad55e4f879c70cf1a40526cfc9f35411195822c535ed
```

Comment: Can you provide an example (not using *any* private data) of PHP inputs and outputs and the corresponding output from Ruby of same?

Comment: @tadman I edited the code above to show you how it's used. As you can see, the signatures mismatch. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in Ruby:

```
hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, [key].pack('H*'), message)
```

The real issue here is that your PHP code uses two variable names for the message.  You set `$message`, then use `$msg`, which means you're computing the hash for an undefined variable.

Comment: God I'm ashamed... Thank you!

Comment: Don't feel bad, we've all been there.  I figured it out because I used another method to calculate the actual hash, found that Ruby was correct (when using the actual key as above), and then worked to see why PHP was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The packing of the hex **representation** of the key back into a binary form is the bit you're missing.

See this post for example: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/07/20/ruby-pack-unpack.html

You'll want something like this:

```
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, key.pack('H'), message)
```

Comment: Hello Damon, thanks for your input. The pack method is undefined for the String class (which key is). I tried with `[key].pack('H')` and `[key].pack('H*')` but the hex output still differs from the one I get with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in my project:

```
bin_key = Array(keyTest).pack 'H*'
@hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("SHA512", bin_key, msg).upcase
```

This works fine for me.